# Where did my backslashes go?

Tags: json, shell, escaping, zsh

I have a JSON structure, escaped inside another JSON structure, escaped inside another JSON structure.

`cat` shows the file contents just fine:

```
 cat test.json 
{
  "payload": "{\"data\":\"{\\\"nested\\\":1}\"}"
}
```

I want to assign this to a variable in `zsh`.

But I am finding that my every attempt to return the `cat` output from a subshell, gives me the wrong number of backslashes.

```
 X="$(cat test.json)"
 echo "$X"
{
  "payload": "{\"data\":\"{\\"nested\\":1}\"}"
}

 echo $(cat test.json)
{ "payload": "{\"data\":\"{\\"nested\\":1}\"}" }

 echo $(<test.json)
{ "payload": "{\"data\":\"{\\"nested\\":1}\"}" }
```

Where did my backslashes go? Can I get them back?

I am using `zsh 5.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.0)`.

Comment: which version of bash do you use? I cannot reproduce your problem on bash-4.3.46 (ArchLinux)

Comment: Ah, okay; looks like the problem was that I was using `zsh`. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is being set to the correct value. <strike>You are either using `dash`, not `bash`, or your `bash` shell has the `xpg_echo` option set.</strike> The `zsh` built-in `echo`, though, behaves according to the POSIX specification, which replaces certain escaped characters. Try using `printf` instead:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$X"
{
  "payload": "{\"data\":\"{\\\"nested\\\":1}\"}"
}
```